# Are Linear Bounded Automatons Turing Complete?

Tags: turing-machines, turing-completeness, church-turing-thesis, linear-bounded-automata

[Linear Bounded Automatons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_bounded_automaton) are just Turing Machines with finite tape, instead of infinite tape.

But this causes them to not be Turing Complete? Why?

Answer (score 4):

A linear bounded automaton is a Turing machine that runs on input of size $n$ in $\mathcal{O}(n)$ space. By the space hierachy theorem there exist languages that need e.g. $\omega(n^2)$ space.

Answer (score 2):

You know that Turing machines can accept languages that aren't recursive.

A linear bounded automaton (LBA) running on word $\omega$ has a *finite* tape at it's disposal, so the total number of configurations (tape contents, head position, state) is finite. For a given word $\omega$ you can go through all possible computations of the automaton (by the above, there is a finite number of computations that don't lead to loops) and check if it accepts or not. Thus LBAs accept only recursive languages. Turing machines are strictly more powerful.