# Difference between linear bound automata and a Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines, automata, context-sensitive, linear-bounded-automata

Can anyone give an example where a language can be rejected by linear bounded automata and accepted by a Turing machine. Is there any proof that a linear bounded automata is less powerful than a Turing machine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are Linear Bounded Automatons Turing Complete?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/110945/are-linear-bounded-automatons-turing-complete)

Comment: @ttnick it answers partially

Comment: @ttnick can i say that one of the difference is there will be no epsilon on the LHS side of productions of LBA but in a turing machine, epsilon productions can exist on the LHS side?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that linear bounded automata are precisely all TM's who use $O(n)$ space.

Now, by the [space-hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_hierarchy_theorem), for any $f$ where $n=o(f)$ (for an extreme example, $f(n)=2^n$) we would have $DSPACE(O(n))\subsetneq DSPACE(O(f))$.

Thus there are languages who require space complexity bigger than $O(n)$, and therefore are not solveable by linear bounded automata but can be solved by a ($O(f)$ space) turing machine.

Comment: Can you give any example of such language which is rejected by LBA but accepted by a Turing machine?

Comment: Can i say that one of the difference is there will be no epsilon on the LHS side of productions of LBA but in a turing machine, epsilon productions can exist on the LHS side?

Comment: What do you mean by epsilon productions?

Comment: And for an example, take a look at the proof: It builds a language in $O(f)$ that is not in $O(g)$, for $g=o(f)$. In our case, $g(n)=n$.